# How can I display presentation slides from a PDF on a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

So, I'm creating a website that is going to be used for training new employees, and I was asked to create bootstrap modals that contain presentation slides of the material. The idea that I had was to create the modal and call on the PDF slides, but I have no idea how to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not a solution unto itself -- hence just leaving this as a comment -- but fwiw you can specify the page number of a pdf in a URL with `#page=n`; eg, http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf#page=3